# req.flash() requires sessions

Tags: node.js, express

I have a problem with flash at views. I am using connect-flash.

there is my configuration

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.cookieParser('secret'));
app.use(express.session());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  res.locals.flash = req.flash
  next()
})
```

here I set flash message at controller action

```
exports.new = function(req, res){
  req.flash('info', 'test')

  res.render("session/new", {
    title: 'Log In!'
  })
}
```

and then, when I am trying to use flash('info') at view, I am getting this error

> req.flash() requires sessions

I am new to nodejs, so excuse me please if it's stupid question.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you called `req.session.destroy()` before the flash-data is passed to `res.locals`?!

Comment: Yes i did because i want to logout the user.Then what should i do in my case...?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/jeromeetienne/1002105) link. It seems you have to specify it when you're **configuring** your express server.

Comment: Thanks, but at page that you've provided dynamicHelpers are used, which are deprecated at express 3.0 and above

Answer (score 0):

Try the `Redirect` instead of `render`.

Ex.

```
res.redirect('session/new');
```